# hostname changing when network changes

Tags: networking, dns, localhost, hostname

My hostname changes whenever the network changes, is there any way I can have one host name all the time.

Following is the output of /etc/hosts -

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Contents of /etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
```

Now, the hostname is shown as dhcppc5, on doing a hostname  -a , output is -

```
hostname : Unknown host
```

Due to this I am not able to start java server applications as they can't resolve the hostname.
How do I solve this.

Comment: well, none of those are actual hostnames, just mappings for localhost, which with AVAHI will add the .localdomain nomenclature. have you actually tried to set a hostname? http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/07/how-to-change-the-hostname-of-a-linux-system/ it will not appear in /etc/hosts however because it is just a hostname, and does not have an IP associated with it statically.

Answer (score 0):

first of all we change hostname of server in **/etc/sysconfig/network** like
**NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=name_of_host**
then save it :wq!
Now we change temporary or with out reboot serer change hostname with hostname command
**# hostname name_of_host**
we can check hostname with **hostname** and **uname -n** command and when we reboot the server its set permanently as see in  /etc/sysconfig/network file output